# AuditEvent AUTHORIZATION_SUCCESS not fired in OAuth2 Resource Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-actuator

According to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-authentication-audit) article, and many others on the web, Spring Boot Actuator provides out of box support for Security Auditing, by using the Actuator endpoint `/auditevents` and by listening to the `AuditApplicationEvents`.

Im testing the `Spring Boot v2.1.0.RC1` with `Spring Security v5.1.1` and the OAuth2 Resource Server for validation of JWT and user authentication, see the code at Github [ismarslomic/spring-security-resourceserver-example](https://github.com/ismarslomic/spring-security-resourceserver-example).

The authentication/authorization part work as expected, with use of Google as IDP. However, `AUTHORIZATION_SUCCESS` event is never fired from Spring Boot Actuator. The only event fired and caught by [LoginAttemptsLogger](https://github.com/ismarslomic/spring-security-resourceserver-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/spring/resourceserver/LoginAttemptsLogger.java) is the `AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE`, when I drop adding JWT in `Authorization` header.

Anything Im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This showed to be a bug in Spring Security, which has been resolved in version `5.1.2` and `5.0.10`. See more info at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14921